# NavigationSplitView - SwiftUI.AnyNavigationPath.Error.comparisonTypeMismatch

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Receiving error:

```
SwiftUI/NavigationColumnState.swift:520: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: SwiftUI.AnyNavigationPath.Error.comparisonTypeMismatch`
```

When a NavigationSplitView's detail view changes, and the detail view moving from has a `NavigationStack(path: ...)`.

This seems like a bug, though usually when I think that I've done something silly. Would love to know a workaround or fix if anyone can figure it out.

**Xcode:** Version 14.3 (14E222b)
**Simulators:** iPad Air (5th Generation) / My Mac (designed for iPad)

**Models**

```swift
import SwiftUI 

final class AppModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var appNavigation: AppNavigation? = .lists
    @Published var listsNavigation: [ListsNavigation] = []
    @Published var settingsNavigation: [SettingsNavigation] = []
}

enum AppNavigation {
    case lists, settings
}

enum SettingsNavigation {
    case settings1, settings2
}

enum ListsNavigation {
    case favourites, notes
}
```

**App.swift**

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct splittyApp: App {
    @StateObject private var model = AppModel()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationSplitView {
                List(selection: $model.appNavigation) {
                    NavigationLink(value: AppNavigation.lists) {
                        Label("Lists", systemImage: "list.clipboard")
                    }
                    
                    NavigationLink(value: AppNavigation.settings) {
                        Label("Settings", systemImage: "gearshape")
                    }
                }
            } detail: {
                switch model.appNavigation {
                case .lists: ListsView()
                case .settings: SettingsView()
                case .none: Text("Error")
                }
            }
            .environmentObject(model)
        }
    }
}
```

***ListsView**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ListsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: AppModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $model.listsNavigation) {
            List {
                NavigationLink(value: ListsNavigation.favourites) {
                    Text("Favourites")
                }
                
                NavigationLink(value: ListsNavigation.notes) {
                    Text("Notes")
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: ListsNavigation.self) { value in
                switch value {
                case .favourites: Text("Favourites View")
                case .notes: Text("Notes View")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SettingsView**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: AppModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $model.settingsNavigation) {
            List {
                NavigationLink(value: SettingsNavigation.settings1) {
                    Text("Settings 1")
                }
                
                NavigationLink(value: SettingsNavigation.settings2) {
                    Text("Settings 2")
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: SettingsNavigation.self) { value in
                switch value {
                case .settings1: Text("Settings 1")
                case .settings2: Text("Setings 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Project:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/jlxct4qeac8kt75/splitty.zip?dl=0

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Launch app on iPad
- Tap between main app navigation (lists/settings)

Comment: your code runs fine with me (Xcode 14.3, iOS 16.4 Simlulator). The error seems not to result from the code you posted.

Comment: Sorry thank you for pointing that out. It looks like maybe it was incomplete. I updated the code in the post but also added a very small example project people can download to reproduce. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs because you use two different navigation enum types in the detail view `NavigationStack`.

Even though you define two `NavigationStack`s, one in each detail subview, SwiftUI creates only one. So these two codes act identical:

```
NavigationSplitView {
    ...
} detail: {
    View1()
    View2()
}


View1() ... {
    NavigationStack(path: $pathA) { ... }
}

View2() ... {
    NavigationStack(path: $pathA) { ... }
}
```

is identical to:

```
NavigationSplitView {
    ...
} detail: {
    NavigationStack(path: $pathA ? $pathB ?) { // which type?
        View1()
        View2()
    }
}

View1() ... {
}

View2() ... {
}
```

The second version makes it apparent, why SwiftUI struggles. It finds values of two different types in the path.

The documentation says it, but in a quite cryptical way:

> You can also embed a NavigationStack in a column. ... Activating a
> link in the same column adds a view to the stack. Either way, **the
> link must present a data type for which the stack has a corresponding
> navigationDestination(for:destination:) modifier.**

**Solution:**

The solution for the problem is to use the special type erased `NavigationPath` for both path vars. It has been introduced exactly for this purpose:

```
final class AppModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var appNavigation: AppNavigation? = .lists
    @Published var listsNavigation = NavigationPath()
    @Published var settingsNavigation = NavigationPath()
}
```

Comment: So far it appears this may be the only reasonable solution. The issue then becomes introspection because of the type-erasing nature of NavigationPath. Any ideas for how to make the path stack more transparent short of Building a custom NavigationPath-like component?

Comment: @esreli The documentation to `NavigationPath` gives an example to serialise the content of it when types conform to `Codable`.  You could read out that encoded result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ChrisR. That works but theres an issue of the NavigationPath popping. If I enter a sub-view in 'Lists', switch root tab to 'Settings', then back to 'Lists', the sub-view isn't presented. I thought it would persist. Similarly, going between tab/sidebar states via split view causes it to be there on a few changes until it decides not to be. Example (Tab/Sidebar pending split state) Example - https://www.dropbox.com/s/re8m7h4p40kb79n/splitty2.zip?dl=0

This is different to the original problem  of the crash mind, so If I can't figure out I'll raise another question.

Comment: curious, did you ever find a solution to the above problem you mentioned?

Comment: @Joey not yet...

Comment: @ChrisR that could solve for how to read the path (albeit in an expensive way), what if we wanted to mutate the path in a way that is not supported by NavigationPath?